# restore version on a list item in REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, flow, version-history

I need to iterate through a list and go to each version history and restore a certain version.. I am doing all of this with MS FLOW.

I am trying to get the `restoreVersion` working like [Restore a previous version of a ListItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/listitemversion_restore?view=odsp-graph-online)

I am using this on MS FLOW to get the item to restore and i keep getting an 404 error, any idea whats wrong ?

[image]

Comment: What is an error message? Are you passing correct version-id?

Comment: I am getting a 404 error not found... The version id i am passing is (1)

Comment: You can check from UI, the version id is correct or not.

Comment: The doc link you posted is for OneDrive, not SharePoint. SharePoint has a different API, and apparently only allows restoring versions of document library items, not regular lists.

Comment: SharePoint CSOM or REST v1 don't implement this method for item/versions, even though it appears on the SPListItemVersionCollection. But it is listed in REST v2 (so you have to go via _api/v2.0/sites/guid/lists/guid/items/id/versions/label/restoreVersion, but this requires explicit app permissions): https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitemversion-restore?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing version ID in your REST endpoint, you are passing `VersionLabel`.

To check the correct version ID of your list item, use below URL:

```
siteUrl/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items(itemId)/versions
```

And search for `VersionId`. It will give you the correct version ID of list item.

I have enabled the versioning on my list and it is creating a major version each time the item is edited.

So, for `VersionLabel = 1.0`, VersionId is `512` and for `VersionLabel = '2.0`, VersionId is `1024`.

**Reference**:

[How does versioning work in a SharePoint list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-does-versioning-work-in-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-0f6cd105-974f-44a4-aadb-43ac5bdfd247).

Comment: yep completly get that - understood and i easily get the number from my other bits of code... but when i use POST and enter /restoreVersion on the end of the url , i get an 404 .. its like the restoreVersion part is broken.

Comment: any idea why RestoreVersion is not working ? I am getting an 404.... can anyone help ?

Comment: All , this is getting urgent now , just wandering if anyone can help me

Comment: has anyone got any advice or how to do this as this is a struggle... please..

Comment: What error are you getting now? Is there any additional error text you can provide? Also, try doing the same using JavaScript/JQuery(Ajax or something) REST API instead of Flow to check if it works or not.

Comment: there is no error... I am trying to do it with Fiddler at the moment , I was thinking of javascript on a Sharepoint page.

Comment: Yes, try using javascript on SharePoint classic web part page.

Comment: Have you tried using JavaScript? Is it working for you?